# 0x Protocol Error: No default contract addresses found for the given network id

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I got these errors while I was running 0x Protocol backend launch kit.

```
WARNING: Multiple definitions for safeTransferFrom
Error: No default contract addresses found for the given network id (137). If you want to use ContractWrappers on this network, you must manually pass in the contract address(es) to the constructor.
    at Object._getDefaultContractAddresses (/home/ubuntu/smartdex-backend/node_modules/@0x/contract-wrappers/src/utils/contract_addresses.ts:10:15)
    at new ContractWrappers (/home/ubuntu/smartdex-backend/node_modules/@0x/contract-wrappers/src/contract_wrappers.ts:118:19)
    at new OrderBook (/home/ubuntu/smartdex-backend/ts/lib/orderbook.js:96:34)
    at new Handlers (/home/ubuntu/smartdex-backend/ts/lib/handlers.js:64:27)
    at /home/ubuntu/smartdex-backend/ts/lib/index.js:19:22
```

I forked this repository:
github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit-backend

Comment: Did you fork this repository? https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit-backend?

Comment: Yes, right. I forked 0x protocol launch kit. Frontend, backend and contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused because of the dependency problem. The 0x Protocol launch kits are using "@0x/contract-addresses" package for contract wrapper.

This is a very tricky solution.

Clone the 0x-launch-kit-backend **(v2)** in the same parent directory with 0x-monorepo. Don’t install the dependencies yet!

Open yarn.lock file and replace all line "@0x/contract-addresses" "^3.0.1" with "@0x/contract-addresses" "file:../0x-monorepo/packages/contract-addresses".

Now install the dependencies with –-frozen-lockfile flag

$ yarn install --frozen-lockfile

Then it will fix the issue.

Comment: If I install the dependencies already, should I remove node_modules and try this again?

Comment: Sure. You have to remove node_modules before yarn install --frozen-lockfile.